# DROOLS : Enable @PropertyReactive directly from builder

Tags: eclipse, drools, builder

I’m using Drools V 6.5.0 and Eclipse Neon.2 V 4.6.0

I’m desperatly trying to enable “@PropertyReactive” Drools annotation on all classes that I have previously created on Eclipse.
According to the documentation (see at the bottom of this topic), it can be done “manually” by annotating “@PropertyReactive” directly on java classes files. However, my model generates interfaces instead of classes. I have even though try on thoses interfaces but unsuccessfully.
Again, according to Drools release, there is another way to enable all classes as “PropertyReactive” directly from the RulesManager file by using an option of the KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration. The problem is that I can’t build anything from this object and so on, I really don’t know what to do with this KnowledgeBuilder.

Anyone already had a similar problem and succeed to fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

Here are Drools documentation (V6.5.0) : _https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/

```
public class RulesManager {

     private RulesManager() {
        super();

     KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

     KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration config  = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();
     config.setOption(PropertySpecificOption.ALWAYS);
     KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(config);

     KieFileSystem kfs = createKieFileSystemWithKProject(ks, false);
     ReleaseId releaseId = KieServices.Factory.get().newReleaseId("com.toto.test", "rules", "1.0-SNAPSHOT");

     kfs.writePomXML(getPom(releaseId));

     try {
        URL url = new URL("platform:/plugin/com.toto.test/defaultkiesession/toto.drl");
        InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        kfs.write( "src/main/resources/toto.drl",
                    ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource( inputStream ) ); }



    kfs.generateAndWritePomXML(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());


    KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs );

    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults(); 
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question, this will help

Comment: Not sure whether referring to facts via interface names and setting @PropertyReactive on implementing classes will work. But trying `declare SomeClass @propertyReactive end` in the DRL is worth the simple effort.